# setMinimumLoggingLevel to VERBOSE leads performance degradation

Tags: android, fresco, imageloader

I am using fresco to loading image in a ListView. Each list item contains about 25 images. When I enable fresco log by call 
    FLog.setMinimumLoggingLevel(FLog.VERBOSE);
I saw a huge performance degradation, setting image on 25 images cost about 6-10ms. However when fresco log disabled, it only cost 1-2ms. Can anyone explains the reason?

Comment: Because generating lots of log messages takes time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fresco is doing additional logging for debugging purposes if it's set to Verbose. Not only do the printing statements slow this down but also additional computations for debugging purposes.

You can see these log instances here: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=FLog.v&type=